# How do I create Pivot Cache using a defined range as data source without a type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a fairly simple pivot table, but I have trouble dealing with pivot cache creation. Both data source and data type seem to be correct yet I get an error. I searched for similar issues but none of the verified answers worked for me.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

'On Error Resume Next
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Regions").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Regions"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Regions")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Set Pivot table Cache

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2),TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    End With

    'Insert Data Field
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Pkt avg")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlAverage
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Name = "pkt avg"
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Number of apt")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 2
    .Function = xlCount
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Name = "Apt num"
    End With

End Sub
```

I get the type mismatch error here `Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2),TableName:="SalesPivotTable")`

Comment: Remove the `.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2),TableName:="SalesPivotTable")`... and then see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create) for commentary on the `SourceData` parameter: "When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly."

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

'On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Regions").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Regions"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Regions")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Set Pivot table Cache

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="SalesPivotTable")

    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    End With

    'Insert Data Field
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Pkt avg")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlAverage
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    '.Name = "Pkt avg"
    .Caption = "Pkt Avgs" '~~> can't use same name with field name
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").PivotFields("Number of apt")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 2
    .Function = xlCount
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    '.Name = "Apt num"
    .Caption = "Apt num"
    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```